# printing text as it is in tcl

Tags: text, tcl

like in python i can simply take the whole text in `"""` and it will be stored as you wrote it inside the `"""`'s

```
outText = """ some text that doesn't contain "\n" and 
          everything can be outputted with 1 print command """
print outText
```

Is it possible to hold the whole text inside some kind of brackets and print out the text without `puts`-ing every single line one by one or using `\n` in every end of line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use braces:

```
set outText {some text that doesn't contain "\n" and
everything can be outputted with 1 put command}
puts $outText
```